# Best way to cast Iterator<Object> to a Set<String>, for instance

Tags: java, generics, casting, iterator, set

Casting an `Iterator<Object>` to a `Set<String>`

What would be the cleanest/best practice way?

Comment: I don´t understand the edit, it´s not a matter of generics. Even if you don´t use generics, the casting should be done equally, the generics are used in the example for helping the audience, but if you remove all the tags, the issue /question remains there

Comment: That code is invalid and meaningless, that's the first problem. We must guess what you want in the first place.

Comment: So I'll try: do you have a `Set<A>` and want to return it cast into `Set<B>`?

Comment: Sorry, ill try to explain better. Remove the generics/types and try to make it compile without annotations nor warnings. I know I can loop and iterate and copy each value but I´m looking for a potential hidden cool solution.

Comment: I put an edit that makes it all easy to understand

Comment: Ok... so you got some iterator from somewhere and you want a set out of it? "Casting" is definitely not the term to use here as it only applies to using an existing object as if it were of certain type. You need conversion.

Comment: I thought it would be some nice solution, I looked the APIs but I expected maybe some way in a line without iterating, generics plus casting could well work

Comment: I don't get it... you want to get a `Set<String>` **without** generics? That's something like sayng "I want an integer, but without numbers".

Comment: You are right sorry, now the question is more simple, I put in in an example without ambiguity. What I meant is that is not only a generics thing, but also casting of inner types, because my iterator is typed <A> not <B extends A> and I have to return a converted collection underneath. Ok just forget it and take the new edit as the correct question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public Set<B> getBs(){
    Iterator<A> iterator = myFunc.iterator();
    Set<B> result = new HashSet<B>();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        result.add((B) iterator.next();
    }
    return result;
}
```

But of course, it will fail if all the `A`s returned by the iterator are not `B`s.

If you want to filter the iterator, then use instanceof:

```
public Set<B> getBs(){
    Iterator<A> iterator = myFunc.iterator();
    Set<B> result = new HashSet<B>();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        A a = iterator.next();
        if (a instanceof B) {
            result.add((B) iterator.next();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Using Guava, the above can be reduced to

```
return Sets.newHashSet(Iterators.filter(myFunc.iterator(), B.class));
```

Answer (score 3):

If we are talking about `iterators` and `collections` that need to use them, and you need the `iterater` to be generic enough so that it can be used by different `collections`.
Just use `if/else` with `instanceof` keyword as follows:

```
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
  Object obj = iterator.next();
  if (obj instanceof A) {
    collection.add((A) o);  
  } else if (obj instanceof B) {
    collection.add((B) o);  
  } else if ...etc
}
```

Comment: I am not the downvoter but in one way I can understand him/her. This code is not very clean and I don't see many use-cases for it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm still not 100% sure what you want, but check this out and see:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  final Iterator<?> it = Arrays.asList(new Object[] {"a", "b", "c"}).iterator();
  System.out.println(setFromIterator(it));
}

public static Set<String> setFromIterator(Iterator<?> it) {
  final Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>();
  while (it.hasNext()) s.add(it.next().toString());
  return s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the only way, probably.

```
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
  Object o = iterator.next();
  if (o instanceof B) {
    collection.add((B) o);  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`org.apache.commons.collections.IteratorUtils` can be used to do this.

Here is an example to convert iterator to set;

```
Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>(IteratorUtils.toList(myIterator))
```

Answer (score 0):

You **can not cast** the Iterator to Set directly. Iterator pattern provides the way to access the elements of an aggregate object sequentially without exposing its underlying presentation. The possible solution is to **travel each elements sequentially** and add each element to the set

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Object obj = iterator.next();
    set.add(obj.toString());
}
```

Comment: I meant casting for the inner types. If Object didnt have a toString method it would need a cast (the original question was with A and B type). Correct me if I´m wrong.