# Build iterator for an interface, using the child

Tags: java

So I have a `hashmap<x,y> myHashmap`

x implements z.

I want to get an iterator for z.

Since x is a "child" of z, this shouldn't be hard, but I can't think of how to do it.

My attempt:

```
return (Iterator<z>) this.myHashmap.keySet().iterator();
```

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Trying to implement a function with a set return type.

Comment: You can refer to this: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581561/best-way-to-cast-iteratorobject-to-a-setstring-for-instance).

Comment: `Collections.unmodifiableMap(this.myHashmap).keySet().iterator()`.

Comment: @KCWong That's the wrong direction.

Comment: @LouisWasserman That doesn't change anything. How do I change to hashmap<z>?

Comment: @User: So just swap the classes? That SO thread means there's no way to cast an Iterator. You construct a new map and move the items over.

Comment: @User `Collections.unmodifiableMap` lets you turn a `Map<SubFoo, SubBar>` into a `Map<Foo, Bar>`.  You might need explicit generics, though.